# Why would performance timing data showing domComplete before connectStart and connectEnd?

Tags: web, browser, web-performance

I have a simple uncachable (`Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=0`) document which I'm recording timings in. When loading this document via clicking on a gmail link in latest Firefox, the resulting data is confusing. All of the dom-related timestamps are BEFORE the connection info. This happens consistently whenever I click on the link from Gmail, and I haven't been able to otherwise repro it.

Additionally, `responseStart` and `responseEnd` occur 300 ms after everything else.

Here is the performance data, as shown by the browser console after loading the document:

```
{
  "redirectEnd": 0,
  "redirectStart": 0,
  "unloadEventEnd": 0,
  "unloadEventStart": 0
  "domLoading": 1461369761934,
  "domInteractive": 1461369761968,
  "domContentLoadedEventStart": 1461369762003,
  "loadEventStart": 1461369762006,
  "domComplete": 1461369762006,
  "domContentLoadedEventEnd": 1461369762006,
  "loadEventEnd": 1461369762008,
  "navigationStart": 1461369762030,
  "connectStart": 1461369762031,
  "connectEnd": 1461369762031,
  "domainLookupEnd": 1461369762031,
  "domainLookupStart": 1461369762031,
  "fetchStart": 1461369762031,
  "requestStart": 1461369762031,
  "responseStart": 1461369762313,
  "responseEnd": 1461369762371,
}
```

Am I misunderstanding something here, or have I hit a bug with performance timing data in FF? The same thing does not occur in Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: According to [the spec](http://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#process) (look under the "Process" header), this should be impossible... Therefore I have to think it's a Firefox bug.